# Laravel Queue Timeout Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I am creating Laravel Jobs for sending emails and add them in Laravel Queue. Everything works fine, but the timeout of laravel queue is 300 seconds. How can I extend this time? Or I want to run this queue listen forever because anytime mails can be send due to user interaction. Any one can help?

Answer (score 2):

To run a queue listener in the background, you need to configure it via [Supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration) which is a process monitor for Linux. You can even assign the number of workers using this.

To configure the timeout, you can use the option [timeout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts) in the queue:listen command. The command will be:

php artisan queue:listen --timeout=500

Comment: Thanks. But is there any option to run queue infinitely without supervisor.

Comment: If you are talking about local development, you can run your listener in one terminal tab or use [shell](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=shell+linux+commands&oq=shell&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j0l4.2674j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Or you can use 'sync' as a queue driver which does not require a listener to run but will execute your jobs synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

The best way, You need separate data by page push to queue, instead of 1 queue large data, we have many queues waiting run backgrounds, if in you increase speed, you can make multiple jobs cath queue